# How to convert a few lines of code from vb.net to its c# equivalent

Tags: c#, vb.net, file-io, try-catch, converters

I'm tasked with converting some older VB.net code to C#. Been slowly chipping away at the errors -went from about 100, down now to ~10. The first vb.net code that needs to be converted is:

```
Try
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strFile, strExportPath + "\" + strFileName(0), FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    intFilesCopied += 1

    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(strFile, _strPath + "Data\Backup\" + strFileName(0), FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
    intFilesMoved += 1

Catch ex As Exception
    My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "ExportDataToolStripMenuItem_Click")

End Try
```

My C# attempt is as follows:

```
try
{
    File.Copy(strFile, strExportPath + @"\" + strFileName[0], UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs,
    FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing);
    intFilesCopied += 1;

    File.Move(strFile, _strPath + @"Data\Backup\" + strFileName[0],
    UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, UICancelOption.DoNothing);
    intFilesMoved += 1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "ExportDataToolStripMenuItem_Click");
}
```

The next piece of VB.NET is the catch portion of the try-catch clauses.

```
My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "Could not write record to data file " + _strActiveFileName + Environment.NewLine + "Record Data: " + strRecordText);
```

And for the life of me, cannot find the C#-equivalent for this.

I've tried adding the Microsoft.VisualBasic dll/reference/namespace, but that doesn't work either. Tried to google the C#-equivalent, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Are you aware of this translater tool: [Telerik's Code Converter to C# and VB](http://converter.telerik.com/) ? It doesn't support try-catch as is, but it does the job for most of what's inside the try-catch blocks!

Comment: `Application.Log.WriteException`... hmmm how about `Debug.WriteLine(ex);` and then go from there.... whatever else you need to add into that writeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The next piece of VB.NET is the catch portion of the try-catch
>   clauses.
>
> My.Application.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "Could not
>   write record to data file " + _strActiveFileName + Environment.NewLine
>   + "Record Data: " + strRecordText);
>
> And for the life of me, cannot find the C#-equivalent for this.

This can be converted by (with reference to *Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll*):

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ApplicationBase MyApplication = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ApplicationBase();
```

then :

```
 MyApplication.Log.WriteException(ex, TraceEventType.Error, "ExportDataToolStripMenuItem_Click");
```

And you can check the log file with  :

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(MyApplication.Log.DefaultFileLogWriter.FullLogFileName);
```

(just tested on Windows 10)